# Python: Append a list with elements that have evaluated to true in a function

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a function:

```
def mini_distance(pace_data, activity_id):

    condition_count = 0
    false_count = 0
    true_count = 0
    list_of_classified_sessions = []

    print(activity_id)

    #Condition 1
    condition_count += 1
    #between 4500M and 15000M

    if(len(pace_data) in range(45,180)):
        print("1. Array length fits between X and Y: ",len(pace_data)*100,"M.")
        true_count+=1
    else:
        print("1. Array too short or too long: ",len(pace_data)*100,"M.")
        false_count+=1

    if(true_count == 1):
        list_of_classified_sessions.append(activity_id)

    print(list_of_classified_sessions)
```

**My task:**

Check if an array contains a certain number of elements. If true, append index of that array to a list, if not check the next array. Do this for many arrays located in a DataFrame column.

**Parameters**

```
array([  0.        ,   4.91101813,   5.58028665,   5.55841138,
     5.22151485,   5.30403077,   5.68089541,   4.6237671 ,
     5.52696382,   5.26733118])

index of 80
```

Is array length between X and Y?

If so, add 1 to the true_count variable. Otherwise, add 1 to the false_count variable.

list_of_classified_sessions is stores these index values.

**Example**

```
mini_distance(example_array, example_index)
```

Returns the list with the index location of where that array is in a DataFrame:

```
1. Array length fits between X and Y
[80]
```

If the array does not contain a number of elements between the ones specified, an empty list is returned:

```
1. Array length too short or too long.
[]
```

**Correct so far**

**My attempt**

*code*

```
for i in range(0,5):
    mini_distance(df.iloc[i].column_with_arrays, df.iloc[i].index_of_same row)
```

*output*

```
0 #this is the index
Array too short or too long.
[] #not added, correct
1
Array too short or too long.
[] #not added again, correct
2
Array fits between X and Y.
['2'] #add this index to the list
3
Array too short or too long.
[] #index 3 is not added but now my list is empty
4
Array fits between X and Y
['4'] #index 4 is added but where has index 2 gone?
```

**Desired Output**

A list that contains the indexes of all dataframe rows where the arrays have a number of elements between the ones specified:

```
output_list = [2,4,5,99,121,389,...,2112,3116]
```

I hope I have made this clear. Please demand further clarity if required.

Comment: do you need to use this function? if not, I think the result can be obtain by `s_len = df.column_with_arrays.str.len()` and then `output_list  = df.index[(s_len  >= 45)  & (s_len  <= 180) ].tolist()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> index 4 is added but where has index 2 gone?

Hello Murray,

That's actually a declaration scope *problem*. You declared your **list_of_classified_sessions** inside the **mini_distance** function, which means that it is **not** accessible from outside of this function scope, so its value cannot be saved between two function calls: this explains why your array is initialized to **0** every time you call the function.

To achieve what you want, you could simply declare this array outside of the function and mark it as **global**.

An example:

```py
list_of_classified_sessions = [] # Global array declared 

def mini_distance(pace_data, activity_id):

    global list_of_classified_sessions # Now you can modify the global array inside this function
    condition_count = 0
    false_count = 0
    true_count = 0

    print(activity_id)

    #Condition 1
    condition_count += 1
    #between 4500M and 15000M

    if(len(pace_data) in range(45,180)):
        print("1. Array length fits between X and Y: ",len(pace_data)*100,"M.")
        true_count+=1
    else:
        print("1. Array too short or too long: ",len(pace_data)*100,"M.")
        false_count+=1

    if(true_count == 1):
        list_of_classified_sessions.append(activity_id)

    print(list_of_classified_sessions)
```

This should get what you want. Feel free to ask if you got more questions.

J. Smith

Answer (score 1):

Your code generates 5 separate *list_of_classified_sessions* which have one entry each each time your function is called because the variable is assigned within the function, not outside of it.

To get a single loop, define the *list_of_classified_sessions* outside of the function as the output of the loop.

You can do this by changing your function so it is structured like this:

```
def mini_distance(pace_data, activity_id):

    condition_count = 0
    false_count = 0
    true_count = 0
    #list_of_classified_sessions = [] 
    #You don't need to create the list within the function

    print(activity_id)

    #Condition 1
    condition_count += 1
    #between 4500M and 15000M

    if(len(pace_data) in range(45,180)):
        print("1. Array length fits between X and Y: ",len(pace_data)*100,"M.")
        true_count+=1
    else:
        print("1. Array too short or too long: ",len(pace_data)*100,"M.")
        false_count+=1

    if(true_count == 1):
        return activity_id
```

then set up your loop to create a list of the outputs of your 5 function calls.

```
list_of_outcomes = [mini_distance(df.iloc[i].column_with_arrays, df.iloc[i].index_of_same_row) for i in range(5)]
```

This should result in a single output list of the values that are labeled as "true". Also, list comprehensions are always nice ;)